# Displaying date from MySQL database in the d-m-Y format

Tags: php

I am coding for a news website using PHP & MySQL. I want to display date in the d-m-Y format. For that, I have used:

```
$date='<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>'; //'date' is the value from the database
$newdate=strtotime($date);      

$showdate=date("d-m-Y",$newdate);

       echo $showdate;
```

But, I am only getting the date as 1-1-1970 for all extractions. What is the problem?

Comment: where are the two menthods

Comment: put this `action="insert.php"` in second form , else it won't work

Comment: Special characters escaping in the server side is a good way of handling hackers, escape all the special characters from the client to the server. This can protect you from the hackers. Please see the following link for more information [Cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 1):

This is not just enough to avoid hacking. You need to check user input from back end (PHP) also.

Here is the article about validating user input : https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/2013/05/22/php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-the-beginner/

You can also read about sql injection : http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Regarding form action attribute : http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/action-html-attribute/

Now regarding form method :

> Definition and Usage
>
> The formmethod attribute defines the HTTP method for sending form-data
>   to the action URL.
>
> The formmethod attribute overrides the method attribute of the 
>   element.
>
> Note: The formmethod attribute can be used with type="submit" and
>   type="image".
>
> The form-data can be sent as URL variables (method="get") or as an
>   HTTP post transaction (method="post").
>
> Notes on the "get" method:
>
> ```
> This method appends the form-data to the URL in name/value pairs
> This method is useful for form submissions where a user want to bookmark the result
> There is a limit to how much data you can place in a URL (varies between browsers), therefore, you cannot be sure that all of the
> ```
>
> form-data will be correctly transferred
>       Never use the "get" method to pass sensitive information! (password or other sensitive information will be visible in the
>   browser's address bar)
>
> Notes on the "post" method:
>
> ```
> This method sends the form-data as an HTTP post transaction
> Form submissions with the "post" method cannot be bookmarked
> The "post" method is more robust and secure than "get", and "post" does not have size limitations
> ```

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formmethod.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.
To pass data from one form to your php script, you simply create the response script filtering the fields, you can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

**Html**:

```
  <form action="myscript.php" method="post">
       <!-- your values -->
    </form>
```

**Your PHP Script**

```
if(isset($_POST['your_input_name'])):
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['your_input_name']);
    $name = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    # Do something with your input..
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses several different fields for dates, and you do not really say which date it is that comes from the database. However, I think I can answer this with a generic example you can apply to your case. For this answer we will assume you have a variable called $date that holds the value from the database.

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: I have shown the correct fields. I have also used what you recommended, but I am still getting 1-1-1970 as the output.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the date field raw data from the database? This may help me answer you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code:

$dbdate=$row['date']; [This will hold the date from MySql database.]

$newdate=strtotime($dbdate);

$showdate=date("d-m-Y",$newdate);

```
   echo $showdate;
```

I have got correct results.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Your working code is the same as my answer above. As you can see, I passed the date from the database into strtotime and then formatted it with d-m-Y and the date command.

Answer (score 0):

*Please add as like the following..here first check which value you get from the database in the $row['date']..if you get date here then use following lines to convert d-m-Y format*

```
$date=date_create($row['date']); // but here first check value of $row['date']
echo date_format($date,"d-m-Y");
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!